# sensor package for audio driver

Tags: ros, audio

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am looking package for microphone (ekuilt)  sensor. Could you suggest a good ros package for audio purpose.

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278227/sensor-package-for-audio-driver/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the proper drivers from your microphone are installed you can try: http://wiki.ros.org/audio_common

It'll let you publish your audio stream and such. Never had a big issue with those.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0